# How to maintain values in drop down lists retrieved by JQuery after postback

Tags: jquery, html-select

Basically I used JQuery / Javascript to fill few of my drop down lists, but after the postback it is totaly resetted and it is empty. So I have to click button again to fill them in, and let the user choose the values.

The drop down list with manually defiend options retain their selected position etc ... how can I make sure that the values for other ddl's are also persisted?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function ($) {
        $.fn.cascade = function (options) {
            var defaults = {};
            var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).change(function () {
                    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                    var params = {};
                    params[opts.paramName] = selectedValue;
                    $.getJSON(opts.url, params, function (items) {
                        opts.childSelect.empty();
                        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                            opts.childSelect.append(
                                $('<option/>')
                                    .attr('value', item.Id)
                                    .text(item.Name)
                            );
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $(function () {
        $('#loc').cascade({
            url: '@Url.Action("First")',
            paramName: 'aId',
            childSelect: $('#loc1')
        });

        $('#loc1').cascade({
            url: '@Url.Action("Second")',
            paramName: 'sId',
            childSelect: $('#loc2')
        });
    });

</script>
```

This code just calls some server side functions which returns the list of values

Comment: code would be a grace ...

Comment: ok, just a second, ill update

Comment: Probably I have something like this, quite similar requirements, update a DDL from an AJAX response, but need to take a look at your code first.

Comment: i've updated it ... can you see? Or you need more? )

Answer (score 0):

I have a quite similar approach:

```
jQuery.each(resObject.gaData, function(i, o) 
{
    val = o.id;
    text = o.name + " (" + o.status + "/" + o.serving + ")";
    jQuery('#gacampaign').append(jQuery('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)  );
    if ( someVar == val )
    {
        jQuery("#gacampaign option[value='" + val + "']").attr('selected',true);
    }
});
```

this is within the success handler of an AJAX POST, so, not that generic but quite similar. The only diff is this:

Your code:

```
opts.childSelect.append($('<option/>').**attr**('value', item.Id).**text**(item.Name));
```

My Code:

```
jQuery('#gacampaign').append(jQuery('<option></option>').**val**(val).**html**(text));
```

And for emptying the box I use

```
jQuery("#gacampaign option").remove();
```

Comment: you think this might fix the issue? + i dont really understand how to fix this into my code lol

Comment: it really doesnt work :/I mean it has the same effect, it is cleared after post back